# Array filtering and adding a new object based on key value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filtering, data-manipulation

I have to work with a complex service response, I have to do some manipulation while listing my drag and drop objects.

I think the best way to explain this would be through design and code sharing. I tried to get support from artificial intelligence, but I could not reach the right result because it was a very specific structure.

First of all, I want to explain the logic. I transfer the data sent from the service in a generic way from the left column to the right column using the drag and drop method and add separators between these elements. In this section, the service processes the elements I have allocated and gives a Screen value to the elements in each separator.

For example, when I add a separator at the end of 3 items, the Screen value of the first 3 items becomes 0. The Screen value of what I add after the separator is 1. When I add the second separator, the Screen value of the items below becomes 2. In this way, the user can add as many separators as he wants.

The purpose here is to determine the entries that will be displayed to the user on each screen in the mobile application.

[image: Default]

[image: Dragged]

To create the structure here, I send a request to two different services and determine the left column and right column by comparing and manipulating the two services with each other. In fact, the data in the left column does not change at all, but we can update the data in the right column. I can summarize it as follows: the values in the left column are the default values, and the ones in the right column are the ones we want to select from the default values and show to the user.

Below I will share two service response examples.

Default Values:

```
[
  {
    id: '10d19422-420d-41da-a562-09a1720a2a72',
    name: 'Kilometre Start',
    type: 'INTEGER',
    parent: 1,
    info: 'asdadasdsa'
  },
  {
    id: '98f9592f-05f4-4806-8495-03932c7c74f2',
    name: 'Paket Sayısı',
    type: 'INTEGER',
    parent: 1,
    info: 'asdadasdsa'
  },
  {
    id: 'e4e32b89-ffb5-46f0-87ef-e6ad841cef8f',
    name: 'Gidilemeyen Alınacak Durak',
    type: 'INTEGER',
    parent: 1,
    info: 'asdadasdsa'
  },
  {
    id: '712793d6-28c7-4b53-bdca-47317dab9b7c',
    name: 'Gidilemeyen Durak',
    type: 'INTEGER',
    parent: 1,
    info: 'asdadasdsa'
  },
  {
    id: 'ec3f4342-e37b-4919-bf2e-01c117d6fef8',
    name: 'Dağıtılamayan Paket',
    type: 'INTEGER',
    parent: 1,
    info: 'asdadasdsa'
  },
  {
    id: 'b7a126e6-0e54-40fe-af04-b1ee05cae3e3',
    name: 'Kilometre End',
    type: 'INTEGER',
    parent: 1,
    info: 'asdadasdsa'
  },
  {
    id: '36df0bfa-e18e-48bf-8914-db797c5d049e',
    name: 'Alınacak Paket',
    type: 'INTEGER',
    parent: 1,
    info: 'asdadasdsa'
  },
  {
    id: '3b1476de-9298-4570-a01c-1940edad9977',
    name: 'Alınacak Durak',
    type: 'INTEGER',
    parent: 1,
    info: 'asdadasdsa'
  },
  {
    id: 'c5067777-5602-4214-8963-e64d3fa4d387',
    name: 'Durak Sayısı',
    type: 'INTEGER',
    parent: 1,
    info: 'asdadasdsa'
  },
  {
    id: '1ed7dbbb-0774-4a25-b9ca-7fbd5cc83d70',
    name: 'Gidilemeyen Alınacak Paket',
    type: 'INTEGER',
    parent: 1,
    info: 'asdadasdsa'
  }
]
```

Selected Values:

```
[
    {
      id: 'ad6b98d6-44a3-4025-9a85-1d21a25b9fd8',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: '10d19422-420d-41da-a562-09a1720a2a72',
      order: 0,
      step: 1,
      screen: 0
    },
    {
      id: '3eb56c13-bf3f-4ade-85c4-0b7dd28f8382',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: '98f9592f-05f4-4806-8495-03932c7c74f2',
      order: 1,
      step: 1,
      screen: 0
    },
    {
      id: 'dad8e831-8115-4432-9f45-2561c24b3140',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: 'e4e32b89-ffb5-46f0-87ef-e6ad841cef8f',
      order: 2,
      step: 1,
      screen: 0
    },
    {
      id: '51044bc8-22de-4ebe-b8ca-e096043c4bb5',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: 'b7a126e6-0e54-40fe-af04-b1ee05cae3e3',
      order: 4,
      step: 1,
      screen: 1
    },
    {
      id: '9d9c5184-5d06-49c4-90d0-1894c10f60bf',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: 'c5067777-5602-4214-8963-e64d3fa4d387',
      order: 5,
      step: 1,
      screen: 1
    },
    {
      id: '379c0e55-abfb-4a29-99f6-9807bb0e1f37',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: '1ed7dbbb-0774-4a25-b9ca-7fbd5cc83d70',
      order: 7,
      step: 1,
      screen: 2
    }
  ]
```

I compare these two data with each other and filter by comparing the id in the default values with the attribureId value of the selected values and create the right column.

At this point, I will share with you the body I sent to the service and the data returned from the service.

The Body I Sent to Service:

```
[
  { id: '10d19422-420d-41da-a562-09a1720a2a72', index: 0, step: 1 },
  { id: '98f9592f-05f4-4806-8495-03932c7c74f2', index: 1, step: 1 },
  { id: 'e4e32b89-ffb5-46f0-87ef-e6ad841cef8f', index: 2, step: 1 },
  { id: null, index: 3, step: 1 }, // separator 1
  { id: 'b7a126e6-0e54-40fe-af04-b1ee05cae3e3', index: 4, step: 1 },
  { id: 'c5067777-5602-4214-8963-e64d3fa4d387', index: 5, step: 1 },
  { id: null, index: 6, step: 1 }, // separator 2
  { id: '1ed7dbbb-0774-4a25-b9ca-7fbd5cc83d70', index: 7, step: 1 }
]
```

Response from the service:

```
[
    {
      id: 'ad6b98d6-44a3-4025-9a85-1d21a25b9fd8',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: '10d19422-420d-41da-a562-09a1720a2a72',
      order: 0,
      step: 1,
      screen: 0
    },
    {
      id: '3eb56c13-bf3f-4ade-85c4-0b7dd28f8382',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: '98f9592f-05f4-4806-8495-03932c7c74f2',
      order: 1,
      step: 1,
      screen: 0
    },
    {
      id: 'dad8e831-8115-4432-9f45-2561c24b3140',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: 'e4e32b89-ffb5-46f0-87ef-e6ad841cef8f',
      order: 2,
      step: 1,
      screen: 0
    },
    {
      id: '51044bc8-22de-4ebe-b8ca-e096043c4bb5',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: 'b7a126e6-0e54-40fe-af04-b1ee05cae3e3',
      order: 4,
      step: 1,
      screen: 1
    },
    {
      id: '9d9c5184-5d06-49c4-90d0-1894c10f60bf',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: 'c5067777-5602-4214-8963-e64d3fa4d387',
      order: 5,
      step: 1,
      screen: 1
    },
    {
      id: '379c0e55-abfb-4a29-99f6-9807bb0e1f37',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: '1ed7dbbb-0774-4a25-b9ca-7fbd5cc83d70',
      order: 7,
      step: 1,
      screen: 2
    }
  ]
```

The problem starts at this point. When I do my Drag and Drop I keep this data in this state while actually keeping it as 8 items in the example above. However, when it is processed in the backend service and sent back, the values I send as separator are processed into the response data as Screen values and the data is returned to me as 6 items. So, when the data is remounted after clicking the Save button, the separators disappear and I need to add separators according to the screen values.

What I actually want to do is set a divider object between the last element with a Screen value of 0 and the first element with a Screen value of 1 in the returned data. However, of course, the Screen value here may vary.

Below, I will try to explain in detail the codes by which I filter the data.

My States:

```
  const [stepOneLeft, setStepOneLeft] = useState([])
  const [stepOneRight, setStepOneRight] = useState([])
  const [stepTwoLeft, setStepTwoLeft] = useState([])
  const [stepTwoRight, setStepTwoRight] = useState([])
```

My Handler:

```
 const allAttributesHandler = async id => {
    try {
      setLoading(true)
      const defaultResponse = await Network.getData(`partners/conditions/attributes/partner/${partnerTab}`)
      const selectedResponse = await Network.getData(`partners/conditions/attributes/${id}`)

      // ! Right Sides
      const result1Right = defaultResponse.filter(item => {
        // * Step 1 Right Side
        return selectedResponse?.filter(i => i.step === 1).some(i => item.id === i.attributeId)
      })
      const result2Right = defaultResponse.filter(item => {
        // * Step 2 Right Side
        return selectedResponse?.filter(i => i.step === 2).some(i => item.id === i.attributeId)
      })

      setStepOneRight(result1Right)
      setStepTwoRight(result2Right)

      // ! Left Sides
      const result1Left = defaultResponse.filter(item => !result1Right?.some(i => item.id === i.id))
      const result2Left = defaultResponse.filter(item => !result2Right?.some(i => item.id === i.id))
      setStepOneLeft([{ id: 'divider1', type: 'divider' }, ...result1Left])
      setStepTwoLeft([{ id: 'divider2', type: 'divider' }, ...result2Left])

      setLoading(false)
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading(false)
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

In summary, I want to add separators by manipulating the selectedResponse value according to the Screen values in my function.

manipulated situation example:

```
[
    {
      id: 'ad6b98d6-44a3-4025-9a85-1d21a25b9fd8',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: '10d19422-420d-41da-a562-09a1720a2a72',
      order: 0,
      step: 1,
      screen: 0
    },
    {
      id: '3eb56c13-bf3f-4ade-85c4-0b7dd28f8382',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: '98f9592f-05f4-4806-8495-03932c7c74f2',
      order: 1,
      step: 1,
      screen: 0
    },
    {
      id: 'dad8e831-8115-4432-9f45-2561c24b3140',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: 'e4e32b89-ffb5-46f0-87ef-e6ad841cef8f',
      order: 2,
      step: 1,
      screen: 0
    },
    {
     id:"Random Number",
     type:"divider",
    },
    {
      id: '51044bc8-22de-4ebe-b8ca-e096043c4bb5',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: 'b7a126e6-0e54-40fe-af04-b1ee05cae3e3',
      order: 4,
      step: 1,
      screen: 1
    },
    {
      id: '9d9c5184-5d06-49c4-90d0-1894c10f60bf',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: 'c5067777-5602-4214-8963-e64d3fa4d387',
      order: 5,
      step: 1,
      screen: 1
    },
    {
     id:"Random Number",
     type:"divider",
    },
    {
      id: '379c0e55-abfb-4a29-99f6-9807bb0e1f37',
      conditionId: 'eff2f173-518b-4224-b17f-619cb4ae42e4',
      attributeId: '1ed7dbbb-0774-4a25-b9ca-7fbd5cc83d70',
      order: 7,
      step: 1,
      screen: 2
    }
  ]
```